# Bind a variable in query using a Transformer

Tags: java, jena, transformer-model

I want to bind a specific subject variable within a query.  For instance, supposing that the Op is `subOp`, the following is the transformer that I'm trying to use.  However, at the end, when I print `query`, my subject variable is the same and has not been bound.  Why?

```
Op BindedQueryWithKey = Transformer.transform(new TransformCopy(){
        public Op transform(OpTriple optp, Op subOp){
            Triple tp=optp.getTriple();
            if (tp.getSubject().isVariable() && tp.getSubject().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("userid"))
                {Triple newtp=new Triple(nodeId, tp.getPredicate(), tp.getObject());
            return new OpTriple(newtp);}
            else return optp;
        }
    }, subOp);

    Query query = OpAsQuery.asQuery(BindedQueryWithKey);
```

Comment: It is unlikely the subject as a string is "userid" (a relative URI). Also it is bad to rely on toString in code. Check it is a URI and use `getURI()` on the node and check for the absolute URI.

Answer (score 0):

You have not overridden the `TransformCopy` operation but added a new operation that is never going to be called by `Transformer.transform`.

The signature is `public Op transform(OpTriple opTriple)`.